# SugarCRM - Close access to records based on a value?

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm building a custom module in SugarCRM Community Edition, I have everything set up as i'd like (almost).

In my Module i have a checkbox marked 'Processed' what i'd like to achieve is that when this checkbox is marked, the users who are 'sales agents' and not 'admins' can no longer view this record.

They need to be able to have access to the record up until the point it's marked as processed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, look at /modules/Employees/views/view.list.php in listViewProcess() to see how the list view always filters out users based on the status value. You would do something similar for your module to filter out Processed. Then if you need to also ensure that they can't access the record directly make sure to take care of the edit/detail views as well. In both view.detail.php and view.edit.php (or in the module's controller) check for Processed being set and if so (and perhaps not an admin or some other user type) display a "This record is already processed" message and/or do a redirection.